# Checking my combinatorics

Tags: binomial-distribution, combinatorics

I am modelling a flash memory system where 0.3 requests are writes (and so take 100 cycles to complete) and 0.7 are read-only (and so take 50).

The system can handle 4 requests at once (the proportions are based on observed values but the timings and the 4-at-once are arbitrary).

By my calculation, and assuming the system is "fully loaded" this means 0.2401 probability of 4 read-only, 0.4116 of 1 write and 3 read-only, 0.2646 of 2 writes and 2 read-only, 0.0756 of 3 writes and 1 read-only and 0.0081 of 4 writes.

That all, happily, adds to 1 - but is it correct? My combinatorics is very rusty and online calculators don't allow for proportions.

Comment: You might be amused by the coefficients in the polynomial $(3 + 7t)^4.$  if the connection with your question seems obscure, much more can be found on our site at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+binomial+%5Bself-study%5D+-negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have 4 request, that each of them have a probability 0.3 of being a write request and that the events of each of them being a write request are independent, the number of write requests follow a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters n=4 and p=0.3.

The probabilities of 0 to 4 write requests are:

```
> dbinom(0:4, 4, .3)
[1] 0.2401 0.4116 0.2646 0.0756 0.0081
```

Which confirms your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Pere is right. If you want to get the result by hand, if we make n independent experiments with a success probability of p for each of them, the probability of getting exactly k successful  (ie: "read-only") results is calculated as follows:

**P(k) = p^k *(1-p)^(n-k) * n!/(k! * (n-k)! )**

First factor **p^k** is the probability of getting k consecutive successes.
Second factor **(1-p)^(n-k)** is the probability of getting (n-k) consecutive faillures.
The final term **n!/(k! * (n-k)! )** stands for the possible permutations of the results (it's there because we don't really care if successes and faillures are consecutive or not)

In conclusion, I guess you got it right!